# ASP.Net MVC Server Error in '/' Application

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have been rewriting an application that I did a while ago and when I copied in my views and was trying to see the result after running the application, the homepage did load well, but when trying to navigate between tabs I couldn't.

I got the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
```

The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /MenuItem/Foods

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.3282.0

I have no idea why it cannot find the action. I am using ajax to request the view.

This is the link that I click to take me to the "foods" menu:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Ételek","Foods","MenuItem", null,new AjaxOptions()
                    {
                       HttpMethod = "POST",
                       UpdateTargetId = "page-content",
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    }, new { @class = "nav-bar-link" })
```

Foods method in the MenuItemController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Foods(string foodName, string _category)
    {
        var foodViewModel = new FoodListViewModel()
        {
            Foods = MenuFiltering.GetFoodsToDisplay(foodName, _category),
            Categories = MenuFiltering.GetCategories()
        };

        return PartialView("Foods", foodViewModel);
    }
```

I think the route "/MenuItem/Foods" should work because the method does exist in the controller so I don't know whats the problem.

Comment: You are probably missing the route arguments. Try to use: new { foodName="", _category="" } instead of null after "MenuItem".

Comment: Tested it, but unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Why don't you debug it locally, simplify by doing a standard POST (no Ajax), and see where' you're at?

Comment: I solved the issue, the problem was that I was missing jQuery plugins for the AJAX call.